# ASP Button Edit in GridView ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to make an  Edit button in gridview. So far I can only add a delete asp:button but what about edit button? Is there any way I could modify the CommandField to look like asp:button instead of linkbutton?

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [`ButtonType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfieldbase.buttontype.aspx) attribute to `Button`

```
<asp:CommandField  ButtonType="Button"  ShowEditButton="True"  />
```

Comment: It works! Thanks but it stacked together is there a way I could extend the width of Edit,Delete area?

Comment: @Loupi see if this post helps with the width issue. http://forums.asp.net/t/1318797.aspx/1

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that. You need to write the CSS for links to look like buttons.